# Removing unwanted char from string

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have this function that I have used for a while that removes tabs and other unwanted things from my strings. However I recently wanted to adapt it for using windows paths, so I want to change it so it leaves the : and \ characters in strings. I believe all I need to add the character "\" to the .Pattern line. However I've tried the code below and it doesn't work for some reason, can anyone help?

many thanks

```
Public Function PrepareString(TextLine As String) As String

        Dim oRegex As Object
        If oRegex Is Nothing Then oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        With oRegex
            .Global = True
            'Allow A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, /, :, _ and ' 
            .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 -/\:_']"
            TextLine = .Replace(TextLine, vbNullString)
        End With
        TextLine = Trim(TextLine)

        PrepareString = TextLine

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegEx, `\` is a special character, so you have to escape it with a `\`.

Try this:

```
.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9 -/\\:_']"
```

<sup>That would be the *nix way, at least</sup>